# how to call a controller in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In my ionic blank app, i have two html file index.html and category.html.
i write the controller for index.html in app.js like

```
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.menu = function() {
    console.log('yesytest');
    window.location = "category.html";
  };

})
```

this is working fine and after reaching the category page i create another controller in app.js

```
    controller('categoryCtrl',function($scope){
        console.log('ffffffffff');
    $scope.beauty = function() {
        console.log('yesytest');
        window.location = "categorydetails.html";

    };

});
```

i add a ng-click function on a button inside category.html but when i click on that button it is not calling the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your controller either on : 
- defining it on your ui router state

```
    .state('camera',{
            url:"/camera",
            cache: false,
            controller:"CameraCtrl",
            templateUrl:'app/views/loading/index.html'
    })
```

Or by defining it into tour template category.html

```
<div ng-controller="categoryCtrl"> .... </div>
```

This is standard AngularJS feature, nothing special with ionic

Answer (score 0):

If you use this :

```
.state('category',{
url:"/category",
controller:"categoryCtrl",
templateUrl:'templates/category.html'
})
```

You can use ui-sref="stateId" to do redirection
Example:

```
  <a ui-sref="category"></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

..Hi Kindly route your controller just define them..This might help.. --> http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/ ^_^

//app.js

```
 .state('category',{
    url:"/category",
    controller:"categoryCtrl",
    templateUrl:'templates/category.html'
 })
```

//index.html

```
 <a ng-href="#/category"></a>
```